# Put strings inside quotes with string_to_array()

Tags: sql, postgresql, quotes, string-agg

I am using the following query:

```
WITH a as (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(animals, ',')) as "pets" FROM all_animals where id = 100)
select * from a
```

which returns the following data:

```
1 Cat
2 Dog
3 Bird
```

My question is, how can I format my `string_to_array` select above to include single quotes for the returned data to look like this:

```
1 'Cat'
2 'Dog'
3 'Bird'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`quote_literal()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to safely single-quote strings:

```sql
WITH a AS (
   SELECT unnest(string_to_array(animals, ',')) AS pets
   FROM   all_animals
   WHERE  id = 100
   )
SELECT quote_literal(pets) AS pets
FROM   a;
```

Or shorter without the CTE:

```sql
SELECT quote_literal(unnest(string_to_array(animals, ','))) AS pets
FROM   all_animals
WHERE  id = 100;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=333e856ee0e80c87d14f5f3f51356ffd)*